# Conformance to a protocol (as a protocol)

Tags: swift, protocols

Say I have a protocol `Item`, and a struct `ConcreteItem` that conforms to it.

```
protocol Item {
    var name: String { get }
}

struct ConcreteItem: Item {
    let name: String
}
```

At some point I want to have two sets of `ConcreteItem`.

```
let set1 = Set([ConcreteItem(name: "item1")])
let set2 = Set([ConcreteItem(name: "item2"), ConcreteItem(name: "item1")])
```

Which I'd expect to return the item with name `"item1"`.

---

I can make `ConcreteItem` conform to `Hashable` and the `Set` code will work.  However, lets say I also had the following:

```
struct AnotherConcreteItem: Item {
    let name: String
}
```

I'd like `AnotherConcreteItem` to also conform to `Hashable` simply for having conformed to `Item`.

However, when I try to implement that idea:

```
extension Item: Hashable {
    var hashValue: Int {
        return name.characters.count
    }
}
```

I get the following error: `Extension of protocol 'Item' cannot have an inheritance clause`.

Answer (score 0):

> Extension of protocol 'Item' cannot have an inheritance clause

Here item is the protocol so conforming `Hashable` protocol will not work. For more details Refer [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable)

Comment: Conditional conformances express the notion that a generic type will conform to a particular protocol only when its type arguments meet certain requirements. For example, the Array collection can implement the Equatable protocol only when its elements are themselves Equatable, which can be expressed via the following conditional conformance on Equatable.  https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md

Comment: So in your case its not possible.

Comment: perhaps i can make my heterogenous list of items all of some generically constrained type then.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is possible with some protocols, but not all. If the protocol you are trying to conform to does not have any associated types or `Self`, this is possible.

Example:

```
protocol A {
    func foo()
}

protocol Item: A {
    var name: String { get }
}

struct ConcreteItem: Item {
    let name: String
}

extension Item {
    func foo() {

    }
}
```

Everything that conforms to `Item` will also conform to `A`.

However, `Hashable` has `Self` constraints. To conform to `Hashable`, you must also conform to `Equatable`. To conform to `Equatable`, the implementation of `==` must be in a concrete class, not another protocol because `Equatable` can't be used as a parameter type. The most you can do is something like this:

```
protocol Item: Hashable {
    var name: String { get }
}

struct ConcreteItem: Item {
    let name: String
    // you need to implement == in every concrete class
    static func ==(lhs: ConcreteItem, rhs: ConcreteItem) -> Bool {
        return ...
    }
}

extension Item {
    var hashValue: Int {
        return name.characters.count
    }
}
```

Comment: For `==` you can have a parameter of type `Self` in a protocol extension, see https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/ff678e0fe8e351e655b65ba08d376ba9. Also your current implementation of `==` is incorrect; the requirement of `Hashable` is that two equal types must have the same hash value, *not* two types with the same hash value are equal. In your code, `ConcreteItem(name: "baz") == ConcreteItem(name: "fez")` is true, which is clearly wrong.

Comment: @Hamish Okay, I will let the OP decide what implementation he/she wants